# Echarts 3.0 Values yAxis Rotate

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

I'm having trouble displaying values ​​on the Y axis, only when the screen is smartphone, the values ​​are not displayed entirely.

As exemplified in the figures below:

[image: Chart displayed correctly]
[image: Values yAxis are not displayed entirely.]

The code looks like this, only the part of the yAxis:

```
let option = {
  baseOption: {
    yAxis: {
      name: 'Concentração',
      nameRotate: 90,
      nameLocation: "center",
      nameGap: 30,
      type: 'log',
      scale: true
    }
  },
  media: [{
    yAxis: {
      nameLocation = "end";
      nameRotate = 1;
      nameRotate: 90,
      nameLocation: 'center',
      nameGap: 10
    },
  }]
}
```

**To solve this problem, I would like to know if it is possible to rotate the values ​​displayed on the Y axis.**

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to use the `grid` property in options. It will shift your graph a bit towards the right so that values on Y Axis are visible.
Add this code snippet to your echart options and see if it works

```
grid: {left: '10%'}
```

This will shift to the right by 10% of the container width.

You can find better understanding of `grid` property [here](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#grid)